# Permutations in python but only allowing each element to be used up to n times

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, permutation, python-itertools

I have an array of 30 floats and I need to take all permutations of 4 of this array.

Obviously this gives quite a large number of permutations. I need an efficient way to reduce the number of permutations. I believe that one method might be to restrict each number to only be used up to n (say 8) times to make permutations.

How would this be done? I cant seem to find a way that doesn't use loops to filter out values after computing the complete list of permutations, which would be too slow. Any other suggestions as to how I could reduce the number of permutations would be greatly welcome, I am using python 3. 
Thank you very much

I am currently creating the permutations by using

```py
value_array = np.random.rand(30,)
perm_array = permutations(value_array, 4)
perm_array = np.array(list(perm_array))
data = pd.DataFrame(perm_array, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

A simple example of an output I would like...
IF I have numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and I want all permutations of 2 but only allowing an element to be used 3 times...

I would expect (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (5,6) .... 
Notice that after 1 has been used 3 times it is no longer used, and then the same for 2 and 3

Comment: What are you planning to do with those permutations?

Comment: I have two list of these numbers, one which has undergone a linear transformation, I am then using geometric hashing to characterise the four vectors. Using this code I hope to match it to the geometric hash of the same permutation in the other list. I am following this paper and using the same approach for a slightly different problem, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2233.pdf0910.2233.pdf

Comment: try to add desired output in your question

Comment: mmm, bit hard to without typing out quite a few examples, ill try....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pandas is tagged, here is one way using `itertools` and [`groupby.head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
```

---

```
n=3
[tuple(i) for i in pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(t,2),columns=['A','B'])
                          .groupby(['A'],as_index=False).head(n).values.tolist()]
```

---

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5),
     (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: Note that `t` is the tuple in the OP. Also this solution uses combination